# gnome-core-apps installation

Tags: gnome, ppa

How do you go about installing these? I installed the ppas for gnome 3.10 including the staging and I don't have the core apps that come with gnome. I am on ubuntu 13.10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing?field.series_filter=saucy) has gnome-music. They're not all available unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

They are in Ubuntu [Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-core).

So run;

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-core-devel
```